# std::map get the lowest n elements time

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, binary-tree

`std::map` should be implemented with a binary search tree as I read in the documentation and it sorts them too.

I need to insert rapidly and retrieve rapidly elements. I also need to get the first lowest N elements from time to time.

I was thinking about using a `std::map`, is it a good choice? If it is, what is the time I would need to retrieve the lowest N elements? O(n*logn)?

Comment: when you say "first lowest N elements", you mean sorted by key or by value?

Comment: What are you doing? The requirements sound somewhat unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you need both retrieval and n smallest, I would say `std::map` is reasonable choice. But depending on the exact access pattern `std::vector` with sorting might be a good choice too.

I am not sure what you mean by retrieve. Time to read *k* elements is O(*k*) (provided you do it sequentially using iterator), time to remove them is O(*k* log *n*) (*n* is the total amount of elements; even if you do it sequentially using iterators).

Comment: Time to read _k_ elements is only O(_k_) if you're reading them sequentially using iterators. The time to read a random element is O(log _n_) so the _k_ random elements take O(_k_ log _n_). Of course, in this case they can be read sequentially - but it should be realised this is a special case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use iterators to rapidly read through the lowest N elements. Going from `begin()` to the N-1th element will take O(n) time (getting the next element is amortised constant time for a `std::map`).

I'd note, however, that it is often actually faster to use a sorted `std::vector` with a binary chop search method to implement what it sounds like you are doing so depending on your exact requirements this might be worth investigating.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard requires that all required iterator operations (including iterator increment)  be amortized constant time. Consequently, getting the first N items in a container must take amortized `O(N)` time.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes to both questions.